# Make foreach with nested-if's more compact and readable

Tags: c#

Code works fine.
What I'm looking for is C# syntax to make the **`foreach` loop below** more elegant, compact and readable. The foreach with the multiple if's takes up too much space and looks too ugly. I'm thinking LINQ syntax maybe?

(Assume all the variables are strings. The final version will have better variable naming)

```
public static warMod Gen ( List<AtMap> atMaps ) {

        List<AtMap> atMapList = new List<AtMap>();

        foreach(var a in atMaps)
        {
            AtMap atMap = new AtMap();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.srSys))
            {
                atMap.srSys = a.srSys;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.desSys))
            {
                atMap.desSys = a.desSys;
            }

            if (a.srFl != null)
            {
                atMap.srFl = a.srFl;
            }

            if (a.desFl != null)
            {
                atMap.desFl = a.desFl;
            }

            atMapList.Add(atMap);
        }
        return new warMod {AtMapArr = atMapList}
    }
```

Comment: I think that the code is too simple to be provided a proper review!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please add more context about what the code in question is trying to accomplish to your question. Without seeing the `AtMap` class you won't get much help either, not because we don't want to but because wa can't help you without this class.

Comment: How about moving the body of the foreach (excluding the last line - Add()) to a function, respectively to a method of the AtMap. A static factory method, something like `static AtMap createCopyWithoutEmptyProperties(AtMap atMap)`. I dont see anything wrong with those ifs anyway, you can remove the braces and put the assignment on the same line with the if, but some might consider it bad code style...

Comment: Why not start with good and useful names from the start. Furthermore i agree with @slepic about using a factory method. As you stated you then could simply write `return new WarMod { AtMapArr = atMaps.Select(CreateAtMapForWarMod).ToList()};`

Comment: Innat3's answer of creating a custom constructor seems pretty good, but if you posted more context it seems like you might not even need to copy the AtMap list to a new AtMap list at all. I've learned with a bit of experience that the real benefits don't come from making code look cleaner, they come from using the correct data structures that convey the true intent of the code. In the past I was far too concerned with "cleanness" and I did not understand enough about what actually makes code maintainable (and a little bit of strategic messiness in places is not the end of the world).

Comment: The number one thing that would make this code 1000x more readable is stp w/ abbrvs. I read this and I cannot easily tell the difference between srsys, dessys, srfl, desfl, and so on. Follow good naming conventions; use full words.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare another constructor in your `AtMap` class which initializes the default parameterless constructor, and receiving another `AtMap` as input, performs the value-checking.

```
public class AtMap
{
    public AtMap(AtMap a) : this()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.srSys))
            srSys = a.srSys;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.desSys))
            desSys = a.desSys;

        if(a.srFl != null)
            srFl = a.srFl;

        if (a.desFl != null)
            desFl = a.desFl;
    }
}
```

Then, all you'd have to do is

```
public static warMod Gen(List<AtMap> atMaps) 
    => new warMod { AtMapArr = atMaps.Select(x => new AtMap(x)).ToList() };
```

Comment: This is a good solution. You could make it even shorter if you make a static factory method that calls the constructor, and then it becomes `atMaps.Select(AtMap.Factory).ToList()`

Comment: @OP: If the default values of `srFl` or `desFl` are null, you can remove the conditional from the assignments.  If the default values are not null, you could rewrite `if(a.srFl != null) srFl = a.srFl;` as `srFl = a.srFl ?? srFl;`.  Honestly not sure whether null-coalescing makes it more readable, though.